# Query for "not-in" junction table of many-to-many relationship

Tags: ms-access

I have a many-to-many relationship between PCs and Software Licenses, represented in a third table Installs.

```
+--------------------+
|       tblPCs       |
+--------------------+
| PCID (primary key) |
| ITTag              |
| other useful info  |
+--------------------+

+-----------------------------------+
|              tblLic               |
+-----------------------------------+
| SWLicID (primary key)             |
| SWType (foreign key of tblSWType) |
| other useful info                 |
+-----------------------------------+

+-------------------------+
|       tblInstall        |
+-------------------------+
| InstallID (primary key) |
| PCID                    |
| SWLicID                 |
+-------------------------+

+-------------------+
|     tblSWType     |
+-------------------+
| SWTypeID          |
| SWName            |
| other useful info |
+-------------------+
```

I need a query that returns the `ITTag` of all PCs that do not have a `SWType` installed. I am using the `OnClick` event of a button to run SQL comparing with a text control containing the `SWTypeID` selected by the user.

The current SQL returns all PCs, including those with any license of the specified `SWType` installed.

```
SQL = "SELECT tblPCs.* " _
    & "FROM tblPCs " _
    & "WHERE tblPCs.PCID NOT IN " _
    & "(SELECT I.EqID FROM tblInstall as I, tblLic as L WHERE I.SWLicID = L.SWLicID AND L.SWTypeID = " & CLng(txtSelSW) & ")"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Should `tblLic.SWType` be `tblLic.SWTypeID`?

Comment: Why use a Cartesian product (table list without JOIN keyword) with criteria in the WHERE clause instead of a JOIN and ON clause?

Comment: What is `I.EqID`? `EqID` is not listed in the given schema.  I would guess that this is the problem, assuming that you have an unlisted field EqID, it appears that you have just selected the incorrect field to compare and it should be `I.PCID`.

Comment: Sorry, typo `EqID` s/b `PCID`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are likely many ways to accomplish this, but assuming I've understood correctly, I would suggest using a `LEFT JOIN` on a nested `SELECT` query:

```
SELECT tblPCs.*
FROM
    tblPCs LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT tblInstall.PCID
        FROM tblInstall INNER JOIN tblLic ON tblInstall.SWLicID = tblLic.SWLicID
        WHERE tblLic.SWType = 123456
    ) t
    ON tblPCs.PCID = t.PCID
WHERE
    t.PCID IS NULL
```

Change the `tblLic.SWType` value as required.

Comment: I tried this with the minor mod of referencing the text control thus: `SELECT tblPCs.* FROM tblPCs LEFT JOIN ( SELECT tblInstall.PCID FROM tblInstall INNER JOIN tblLic ON tblInstall.SWLicID = tblLic.SWLicID WHERE tblLic.SWType = CLng(txtSelSW) ) t ON tblPCs.PCID = t.PCID WHERE t.PCID IS NULL` with the proper formatting for inclusion into VBA and I still get the same results as before.

Comment: The logic of Lee's query and the original query are both sound (excepting the possible incorrect column name I pointed out).  I suspect there is a problem with your conversion / comparison of `SWType` with `CLng(txtSelSW)`.  If that condition fails for any reason, the subquery in both statements will return no records, so that all `tblPCs` rows will be returned.  Run a "trace" query (or two) to see what values you're getting without limiting criteria in the WHERE clause.  This technique is critical to proper debugging of SQL, otherwise you naively/blindly trust the expressions in the criteria.

Comment: Something like `SELECT tblLic.SWType, CLng(txtSelSW) As TextValue FROM tblLic` and `SELECT tblInstall.InstallID, tblInstall.PCID, tblLic.SWType, CLng(txtSelSW) As TextValue FROM tblInstall INNER JOIN tblLic ON tblInstall.SWLicID = tblLic.SWLicID`  Manually inspect and verify each value to confirm if it matches what you expect from the textbox field and the raw data in the table records.

Comment: I found my error, which in hindsight is silly and not something anyone else would see without a more in depth view of my form/subforms. Instead of comparing to `CLng(txtSelSW)`, which references a selected software license, I changed it to compare to `cboSESearch`, the combo box in which the user selects the software type. This helps the `OnClick` event to produce the correct results. Thank everyone for their input. @LeeMac your code was what worked with my corrected mistake, so I am marking it as the answer.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted @pegsrob